# Composer - resolve dependencies into the folder of application itself

Tags: dependencies, composer-php

I develop a component (product-delivery) which uses some dependencies resolved via composer. My component supposed to be install to a target application via composer as well. How do I force the composer to load my component's dependencies into its folder instead of a vendor folder of the target application? Take a look a the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your request is no supported use case for Composer. With autoloading properly initialized, you don't need to have PHP classes you are using to be located in a specific folder. If your code does - that's bad and should be fixed.

Perhaps you can add some more details why you'd need to have your dependencies somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, agree. I figured it out and started using a shared vendor folder.